# Character Recognition Using Back Propagation Algorithm Testing

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, backpropagation

Recently I've been working on character recognition using Back Propagation Algorithm. I've taken the image and reduced to 5x7 size, therefore I got 35 pixels and trained the network using those pixels with 35 input neurons, 35 hidden nodes, and 10 output nodes. And I had completed the training successfully and I got weights that I needed. And I've got stuck here. I have my test set and I know I should feed forward the network. But I don't know what to do exactly. My test set will be 4 samples of 1x35. My output layer has 10 neurons. how do I exactly distinguish the characters with the output that I will get? I want to know how this testing works. Please guide me through this stage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used Sigmoid as an Objective function. I trained using backpropagation algorithm

Comment: sorry for being not clear. It's gradient descent.

Comment: sorry @jodag I didn't give much thought between objective function and activation function

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing that each of the output neurons represents one of ten digits? If that's the case then you want label each test set using the index of the output neuron with the highest response.

Comment: Okay, I'll give a clear idea about the network. for an image containing 1 with 5*7 size ->35 input neurons and trained for output [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] and for 2 ->[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] and that goes on for 10 different numbers.

Comment: And if you run a test image what does the output look like?

Comment: what if i get [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0] as an output in testing phase when i give 1 as input. How do I distinguish? does that mean my network is wrong.

Comment: [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0] -> this is what I got when I gave 1 as my test input. sometimes I'm getting all 1's at the output node.

Comment: oh yes, regarding floating point numbers. I am doing this in Matlab. when I get all 1's, my output is like this [1 1.0000 1 1 1.0000 1 1 1.0000 1 1.0000] ->combination of integers and floating point numbers.

Comment: I recommend reading the [LeNet paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) to see a deep neural network architecture that is likely to work. Also [this](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) paper describes the basics of neural networks which should help you if you want to implement your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Surely I will take a look.

Comment: yes. Thanks. This helps me learn more things than usual.

Answer (score 1):

#### One vs All

A common approach for testing these types of neural networks is "one-vs-all" approach. We view each of the output nodes as its own classifier that is giving the probability of the sample being that class vs not being that class.

For instance if you network output [1, 0, ..., 0] then class 1 has high probability of being class 1 vs not being class 1. Class 2 has low probability of being class 2 vs not being class 2, etc.

#### Ties

In the case of a tie, it is common (in research) to have a random function break the tie. If you get [1, 1, 1, ..., 1] then the function would pick a number from 1-10 and that is your prediction. In practice sometimes an expert system is used to break ties. Perhaps class 1 is more expensive than class 2, so we tie in preference to class 2.

#### Steps

So the steps are:

1. Split dataset into test/train set
2. Train weights on train set
3. Pass test set forward through the neural network
4. For each sample, choose the argmax (the output with highest value) as your prediction
5. In case of tie, choose randomly between all tying classes

---

#### Aside

In your particular case, I imagine implementation of this strategy will result in a network that barely beats random performance (10%) accuracy.
I would suggest some reconsidering of the network architecture.

If you look at your 5x7 images, can you tell what number that image was originally? It seems likely that scaling the image down to this size losses too much information that the network cannot distinguish between classes.

#### Debugging

From what you've described I would look at the following when debugging your network.

1. Is your data preprocessing (down-scaling) leeching out too much information? Check this by manually investigating a few of the images and seeing if you can tell what the image should be.
2. Does your one-hot algorithm work? When you convert your targets for training, does it successfully convert 1 -> [1, 0, 0, ..., 0]?
3. Is your back-prop / gradient descent algorithm correct? You should see (roughly) a monotonic decrease in your loss function while training. Try at every step (or every few steps) printing the loss that you are optimizing. Or even for a very simple gut check, print mean squared error: (P-Y)^2